# Preserve Case Replace in Sublime Text 3

Tags: replace, sublimetext3

From having done a bit of googling on this it seems that it is or at least was possible to do this with Sublime Text. I have seen multiple references to a preserve case button in the find and replace pane which looks like 2 rounded squares superimposed on each other.

However, I can't find this at all in my version of Sublime Text 3 (on Mavericks)...

Also I checked preferences to see if this option was somehow turned off but the only reference I could find to it was:

```
{ "keys": ["super+alt+a"], "command": "toggle_preserve_case", "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
},
```

in the default key map file...

Here is a screenshot of my find and replace pane:

[image]

Comment: This is missing for me too in build 3059 as well as build 2221 (on Mavericks). I'm not sure exactly when the preserve case option disappeared.

Comment: @WizardofOgz Have you gone to 'Find' menu and select 'Replace...'? It should be there. I didn't realise that it is not an option in the 'Find in Files' option only within a file.

Comment: @WizardofOgz No prob! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it might have been a glitch in ST3 that was causing confusion.

I noticed that the shortcut key combo for replace has never worked for some reason and also that selecting replace from the find menu opened the find in file pane as opposed to the regular find and replace pane (where the preserve case button is). I only realised this after installing the soda theme for ST3 which showed the preserve case button in a screenshot.

Strangely, when I reverted to the default theme, the find > replace menu now works as it should and I found that the keyboard shortcut was being causght by another program which was why it didn't work...

Answer (score 21):

In the latest Sublime 3 build (3059) there is a dedicated icon in the replace dialog to preserve the case. When toggling it and using the input shown in the screenshot, the following input string will be converted to the following output:

*Input*: "Xhis is my xest."

*Output*: "This is my test."

[image]

Comment: As far as I've seen, it doesn't work very well for programmers trying to preserve case when renaming variables.  I think it just preserves case at each index in the match, rather than doing something more clever like finding word boundaries in camel case, kebab case, etc.

Comment: FWIW this only exists searching in one file: you cannot do this over multiple files

Comment: @SCdF Do you know why it is not possible for multiple files? That's exactly what I need!

Comment: It would be good to note (as SCdF mentions) that this only works in a single file -- it is not an option when replacing over multiple files. It would be nice to have it work over multiple files...

Comment: Just tested this in 2024 and it works fine across multiple files.

Answer (score 15):

It's not exactly an answer to your almost 1.5 years old question, but maybe you (or somebody else) find(s) the following useful:

I wrote a ST package which includes a feature to preserve the case while editing multiple selections. It even preserves cases with separators like snake_case, dash-case, dot.case etc.

It is called [MultiEditUtils](https://github.com/philippotto/Sublime-MultiEditUtils/tree/1.6.4#preserve-case-while-editing-selection-contents). Here you can see the described feature.

[image: The feature in question]

Comment: Fantastic!  If only this were the default behavior of the search/replace with preserve case.

Comment: That's absolutely awesome, you made my day.

Comment: Can somebody bring concrete samples of where you applied .
Because I personally can not imaging how it can be used in a real project.

Comment: Can somebody bring concrete samples of where you needed that.
Because I personally can not imaging how it can be used in a real project.

Comment: @tav Consider a domain-specific name for an entity (e.g., a "user") which you want to rename (e.g., to an "employee"). Now, you might have several identifiers which contain that name (e.g., a "userID" variable, a "UserManager" class and a "USER_GREETING" constant). Due to the different casing (variables, classes and constants often have other case conventions), you cannot resort to a simple search&replace if you intend to rename the variables (to "employeeID", "EmployeeManager" and "EMPLOYEE_GREETING"). That's where the preserve functionality helps.

Comment: OMG thank you... I didn't know how badly I needed this until now!